# Cucumber setup and tear down environment

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I would like to setup an environment, say create servers on Rackspace, before running Scenario Outline Examples, and then destroy the environment, say delete the servers that are created on Rackspace, after test cases are finished, it doesn't matter they are successful or failed.

I have tried to use Before and After, but it seems that it will create and then destroy the servers when it runs every single test case in Examples, what I want is creating the environment for all the cases in Scenario Outline Examples, not just every single one, and then delete it after all the test cases in Examples are done.

This is my code:

```
Feature: Radius Authentication

#Creating servers for the test cases below in the env.rb

@wip
Scenario Outline:
  When the user authenticates <User> with different <MAC> <NAS-ID> via RADIUS
  Then the user <User> should be logged in

  Examples:
  |User|   MAC           |  NAS-ID    |
  | b1 |C0FFEE15F001     |testing-0   |    
  | b2 |C0:FF:EE:15:F0:02|testing-0   |
  | b3 |C0-FF-EE-15-F0-03|testing-0   |
  | b4 |C0FF.EE15.F004   |testing-0   |
  | b5 |C0:FF:EE:15:F0:05| -          |

  #Deleting servers after the test cases above are done  in the env.rb
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the recommended method is to use global variables ([Cucumber docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#global-hooks)).  I imagine you would like something more like rspec's `context` so you can create an environment for a group of scenarios, but someone with more knowledge than me will have tell you whether that can be easily done (I'm not sure if cucumber has anything for that).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks James,

Global hooks

If you want something to happen once before any scenario is run – just put that code at the top-level in your env.rb file (or any other file in your features/support directory. Use Kernel#at_exit for global teardown. Example:

I don’t have to use any special hooks to run setup code when Cucumber starts. Just put your one-time startup code in env.rb, and Cucumber will runit before the first test.

http://media.pragprog.com/titles/dhwcr/global.pdf

```
 at_exit do  ===> hook to tear it down when Ruby exits 
   my_heavy_object.undo_it
 end
```